# How to load the correct language (set in config) instead of the language last in an array

Tags: java

I'm creating a little java app and I'm trying to load the yml files based on config.yml lang set (en/it) but I can't find a way to load them, only the last one in an array is loaded which is "it" for me.

I know that my method is probably the worst solution for a language file, I'm open to every method that will help me with the problem. But I prefer an external lang_en/it file instead of internal ones (Or is it better internal?)

After I set the language, the app will self-update every text in every class.

```
static final Properties props = new Properties();
static WelcomeMessage main = new WelcomeMessage();
static File file = null;
static File folder = null;
static boolean os = main.os.startsWith("Windows");

public static void create() {
    String[] lang = {"en", "it"};
    for (String s : lang) {
        file = new File(WelcomeMessage.user + "/AppData/Roaming/MyApp/lang_" + s + ".yml");
        folder = new File(file.getParent());
        SetLanguages(s);
    }
    if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            if (os) {
                folder.mkdir();
                file.createNewFile();
            } else {
                file = new File(main.user + "/Library/Application Support/MyApp/config.yml");
                folder.mkdir();
                file.createNewFile();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e + " " + file);
        }
    }
}

public static void SetLanguages(String lang) {
    if (lang.equals("en")) {
        store("Settings.Save", "Save");
        store("Settings.ConfigPath", "Config Path");
        store("Settings.Language", "Language");
        store("Settings.Title", "Settings");
    } else if (lang.equals("it")) {
        store("Settings.Save", "Salva");
        store("Settings.ConfigPath", "Percorso config");
        store("Settings.Language", "Lingua");
        store("Settings.Title", "Impostazioni");
    }
}

public static String get(String value) {
    String key = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        props.load(in);
        key = props.getProperty(value);
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception fnf) {
        System.out.println(fnf);
    }
    return key;
}

public static void store(String value, String key) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        props.setProperty(value, key);
        props.store(out, null);
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception fnf) {
        System.out.println(fnf);
    }
}
```

This is how I get a text from yml:

```
path.setText(Language.get("Settings.ConfigPath"));    
language.setText(Language.get("Settings.Language"));    
f.setTitle(Language.get("Settings.Title"));    
save.setText(Language.get("Settings.Save"));
```

And this my Language.get(key)

```
public static String get(String value) {
    String key = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        props.load(in);
        key = props.getProperty(value);
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception fnf) {
        System.out.println(fnf);
    }
    return key;
}
```

Comment: “please don’t help me using other methods” why not? Why’d people help you with turd polishing if they’ve a better idea to do the same thing?

Comment: Did my answer help solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following changes:

1. Create a `Settings` class to hold the properties `save`, `configPath`, `language` and `title`. Even better if this class uses an immutable builder pattern, because once set, the properties will never change.
2. Create a `SettingsFactory` class with method `getSettings(language)`. This class shall also have a field `Map<String, Settings>`. In the constructor (or a static block), first check if a file exists on the disk, and if yes, load it into the map. If not, populate the map, one entry for each language, and persist to the disk.
3. `getSettings` would simply return the value from the map corresponding to the given language.

The format of the file written to the disk is a different matter. You say YAML, but I'm not seeing any YAML specific code in your snippet. If you don't know how to write a map to YAML, open a different question.